# Запятая между однородными придаточными, в одном из которых есть тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, придаточное-предложение

*Это были диванные критики, которые найдут 101 причину, почему **такое дело — пустая трата времени** и **у нас ничего не получится**.*

Здесь однородные придаточное, соединённые союзом "и", однако в первом придаточном между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит тире. Я правильно понимаю, что, несмотря на это, перед союзом "и" всё равно запятая не ставится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы абсолютно правы. Союз и объединяет однородные придаточные, в одном из которых есть тире.  Тире не мешает отсутствию запятой.

Answer (score 1):

> Это были диванные критики, которые найдут 101 причину, почему такое дело — пустая трата времени и у нас ничего не получится.

Запятая между однородными придаточными не ставится.

Стиль разговорный, поэтому можно простить некоторые огрехи, а именно:

- Лучше звучит "1001 причина" (по аналогии с "1001 ночь").
- *Причина* обычно сочетается с действием, например:

> Часто думал, что просто нет никаких биологических **причин**, почему бы человеку не **жить** вечно… [В. Т. Шаламов. Колымские рассказы (1954-1961)]

Вариант исправления:

**Это были диванные критики, которые найдут 1001 причину считать, что такое дело — пустая трата времени и у нас ничего не получится.**